# Encrypt in C# and decrypt in Flex

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, apache-flex, encryption, blowfish

I need to decrypt some data in Flex that is encrypted in C# and written to a file.
I settled on blowfish for simplicity's sake using the as3crypto As3 library and Bruce Schneier C# library.

[AS3 as3crypto link](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/)

[Bruce Schneier C# blowfish link](http://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html)

I can get a short string to encrypt in C# and decrypt in Flex fine
however longer strings just fail to produce results and I do not know what I am missing?

C#:

```
string reportstring = "watson?";
BlowFish b = new BlowFish("04B915BA43FEB5B6");
string cipherText = b.Encrypt_ECB(reportstring);
String plainText = b.Decrypt_ECB(cipherText);
```

AS3:

```
var txt:String =  "watson?";
var key:ByteArray = Hex.toArray("04B915BA43FEB5B6");
var blowfish:BlowFishKey = new BlowFishKey(key);                
var dataBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
dataBytes=Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(txt));
blowfish.encrypt(dataBytes);
blowfish.decrypt(dataBytes);
```

**Update, some samples**

working

> **encrypt string = "watson?"**
>
> **C#** produces: 1514ea36fecfd5f5
>
> **AS3** produces: 1514ea36fecfd5f5

not working

> **encrypt string = "whats up watson?"**
>
> **C#** produces: 3ea9808a4b9f74aaa8e54fe682947673
>
> **AS3** produces: 3ea9808a4b9f74aa20776174736f6e3f

which is very similar but not matching

if I decrypt the AS3 cipher in C# I get :

> whats up?`r???

if I decrypt the C# cipher in AS3 I get :

> whats up¨åO悔vs

Comment: Can you provide an example that gives correct output, and an example that gives incorrect output?

Answer (score 2):

The AS3 code seems to be incorrect. Working example code:

```
import com.hurlant.util.Hex;
import com.hurlant.util.Base64;
import com.hurlant.crypto.Crypto;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric.IPad;
import com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric.ICipher;
import com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric.NullPad;
import com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric.BlowFishKey;

function encrypt($text:String, $cryptKey:ByteArray):String
{
    var iPad:IPad = new NullPad();
    var crypt = Crypto.getCipher('blowfish-ecb',$cryptKey,iPad);
    var cryptText:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    cryptText.writeUTFBytes( $text );
    crypt.encrypt( cryptText );
    trace( Hex.fromArray( cryptText ) );
    return null;
}   

var txt:String =  "whats up watson?";
var key:ByteArray = Hex.toArray("04B915BA43FEB5B6");

encrypt(txt, key);
```

Comment: But how do I get the cryptText bytearray into a string and later decrypt the string?

Comment: @kolaval - That question makes no sense.  `cryptText` is the byte array which contains the encrypted data.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to "how do I decrypt the string afterwards":

```
var encodedtxt:String = Hex.fromArray(cryptText);
cryptText = Hex.toArray(encodedtxt);
crypt.decrypt(cryptText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package
{   
    import com.hurlant.crypto.Crypto;
    import com.hurlant.crypto.prng.Random;
    import com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric.ICipher;
    import com.hurlant.util.Base64;
    import com.hurlant.util.Hex;

    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    import mx.utils.Base64Decoder;
    import mx.utils.Base64Encoder;

    public class EncryptionManager
    {

        public function EncryptionManager()
        {
        }

        public function enCrypt(data:String, keyStr:String):String
        {
            var key:ByteArray;
            var fileBytes:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(data));
            key = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(keyStr));

            var aes:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher("blowfish-ecb", key, Crypto.getPad("pkcs5"));
            aes.encrypt(fileBytes);

            var enc:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
            enc.encodeBytes(fileBytes);
            var result:String = enc.flush();
            return result;
        }

        public function deCrypt(data:String, keyStr:String):String
        {
            var key:ByteArray;

            var dec:Base64Decoder = new Base64Decoder();
            dec.decode(data);

            var fileBytes:ByteArray = dec.toByteArray();
            key = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(keyStr));
            var aes:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher("blowfish-ecb", key, Crypto.getPad("pkcs5"));
            aes.decrypt(fileBytes);
            return fileBytes.toString();
        }

    }
}
```

Try out this Class that might solve your problem.