# Encryption between an ActionScript 3 client and a C# server

Tags: c#, .net, actionscript-3, encryption, client-server

I'm building a Flash-based game that communicates with a WCF web service. Game will be uploading the scores to the server, and I need to make a user to crack the communication as hard as possible. I need a simple encryption method that will encrypt the points using an ever-changing (semi public?)key from the server that changes on every request, even for the same user. I'm aware that THIS can also be cracked in time, but my aim is to make it harder. I've used a very similar method (SHA256) in the past with a C# server *and* client, but this time, my client is ActionScript 3, so I need a library that works the exact way in both .NET and AS3. Are there any built in ones? I'm not a math expert and I really don't want to write my own. I've found [Encrypt in ActionScript3 and Decrypt in asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308781/encrypt-in-actionscript3-and-decrypt-in-asp-net-c-sharp) which is not answered and [Encrypt in C# and decrypt in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993707/encrypt-in-c-sharp-and-decrypt-in-flex) but it uses some external libraries, which I want to use ONLY if I have to.

So, are there any built in library both in AS3 packages and .NET that are compatible with each other?

Comment: ActionScript 3 has no built in Encryption libraries that I'm aware of; why the aversion to using a third-party library like [AS3Crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/)?

Comment: I always prefer built in ones if there are any. If there is no other option, I'll be looking into that.

Comment: https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib includes hashing functions as well. I haven't tried them with c# but SHA 1 and MD5 should be platform-agnostic if properly implemented.